# <pre> tag won't show text containing <iframe>

Tags: html, iframe, pre

Why can't I show my `<iframe>` code line inside a `<pre>`? I need to show this `<iframe>` code  on a page for people to copy/paste. When I write it within a `<pre>` tag, it just renders the actual `iframe` object, rather than outputting the `iframe` code as text on the page.

```
<pre>
    <iframe height="150" width="150" src="http://lorem.com/text.html"></iframe>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to replace `<` and `>` with the respective entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: Is there an html tag that escapes all other html tags except itself, including html comments?